# Почему в цикле if значение QLabel не меняется?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Почему при обычном присвоении текста `QLabel` меняется:

```
self.label.setText('привет')
```

А в цикле нет:

`if self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Пицца': self.label.setText('привет')`

Хочу написать программу, в которой есть `QComboBox`(ComboViborBluda) и `QLabel` (label_2).
В комбобоксе есть несколько значений: Пицца, Гамбургер, Суши.

Нужно реализовать такую штуку:
Основываясь на выборе из ComboViborBluda менять текст в label_2

Грубый пример:
Если пользователь выбрал "Пицца" - Текст label_2 заменить на 'привет'
У меня не получается, причину объяснил выше.

Код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from first_project.project.design_project import Ui_MainWindow


class WayToTheDream(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Way To The Dream!')
        self.setFixedSize(1010, 800)
        self.NazvanieBluda.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 350, 180, 21))

        self.dish_lib()

    def dish_lib(self):
        if self.ComboViborBluda.currentIndex() == 'Гамбургер':
            self.label_2.setText('привет')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WayToTheDream()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**design_project.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1010, 800)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.ComboViborBluda = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboViborBluda.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 310, 211, 22))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setObjectName("ComboViborBluda")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 370, 171, 131))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1010, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "*Блюдо не выбрано*"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Гамбургер"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Пицца"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Салат \"Цезарь\""))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Салат \"Греческий\""))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "Картошка Фри"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "Картошка по-деревенски (Айдахо)"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "Наггетсы"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(8, _translate("MainWindow", "Крылышки"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(9, _translate("MainWindow", "Соусы"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(10, _translate("MainWindow", "Торт \"Тирамису\""))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(11, _translate("MainWindow", "Торт \"Наполеон\""))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(12, _translate("MainWindow", "Роллы"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(13, _translate("MainWindow", "Суши"))
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос больше подробностей: что за цикл, почему Вы так решили, что такое combobox? Добавьте минимально воспроизводимый код с проблемой

Comment: @MrMorgan готово

Comment: Попробуйте использовать currentIndex https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop вместо currentText

Comment: Покажите пример, который вы уже написали и который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick готово, всё описал и добавил код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получать быстрые и правильные ответы, вы должны предоставлять **минимально-воспроизводимый пример**, который демонстрирует проблему.

Если вы этого не делаете, то не понятно о каком `цикле` вы говорите.

Все что вам надо, это использовать сигнал, например `activated()`:

```
self.comboBox.activated.connect(self.comboActivated)
```

Этот сигнал отправляется, когда пользователь выбирает элемент в поле со списком.
Обратите внимание, что этот сигнал отправляется,
даже если выбор не изменен. Если вам нужно знать, когда выбор действительно изменится,
используйте сигнал `currentIndexChanged()` или `currentTextChanged()`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

 
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.addItems(["Сделайте свой выбор:", "Пицца", "Гамбургер", "Суши"])
        self.comboBox.activated.connect(self.comboActivated)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
       
    def comboActivated(self):
        if self.comboBox.currentText() == 'Пицца': 
            self.label.setText(f'Привет `{self.comboBox.currentText()}`') 
        else:
            self.label.clear()


if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(300, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

вот подправленный ваш `main.py`

```
...

class WayToTheDream(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#?        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()                                    # убрать !!!
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Way To The Dream!')
        self.setFixedSize(1010, 800)
#? NazvanieBluda        self.NazvanieBluda.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 350, 180, 21))

        #    comboViborBluda !!!
        self.ComboViborBluda.activated.connect(self.dish_lib)

#?        self.dish_lib()

    def dish_lib(self):
#        if self.ComboViborBluda.currentIndex() == 'Гамбургер':
        if self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Гамбургер':              # ! currentText
            self.label_2.setText('привет')
        else:                                                              # +++
            self.label_2.clear()                                           # +++

...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: self.ComboViborBluda.activated.connect(self.dish_lib())
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Comment: dish_lib() это comboActivated()

Comment: @Drim я дополнил свой ответ, проверьте внимательно.

Comment: Всё работает! Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Drim пожалуйста